# Whats the most precise var type in C, and how to print it

Tags: c, variables, printf

I'm doing a program in C that needs to be very precise, what is the var type and what i have to put  in printf("%")

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you need to store in it?

Comment: Carlos: read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2):

`_Bool`  you can't get more precise than that.

To print a value of that type, use `"%u"`: the value is automatically converted to `int` but in this instance it's ok.

Comment: In fact, I need decimal places

Comment: no, no, `_Bool` is an unsigned type so you should use `"%u"` :)

Comment: @Carlos that was not the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the built-in data types in C/C++ aren't sufficiently precise or have sufficient range for you for some reason, you may like to look at *arbitrary precision* numbers. Those are data types which manage an arbitrary amount of memory to store numbers of, well, arbitrary precision. For integers that means numbers with arbitrarily many digits. Typically this is extended to arbitrary *rational* numbers, i.e. quotients of integers. Moreover, there are also arbitrary-precision *floating point* numbers (you specify the amount of memory you'd like to use) should you need those.

The standard choice of library for C is [GMP](http://gmplib.org), which has all of those features, but if you have specific correctness requirements for floats, you may need the additional [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library, and finally there is also [MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org/) to do the same for complex numbers.